# object in a set iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, set

I can get a method of a class in a set iterator ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
class student{
  public:
     student(std::string n){
        name=n;
     }
     void print(){
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
     }
     bool operator < (const student & s1){ return true;}
     bool operator = (const student & s1){ return true;}
  private:
     std::string name;
};
int main(){
  std::set<student> studs;
  studs.insert(student("name01"));
  studs.insert(student("name02"));
  std::set<student>::iterator it;
  for(it = studs.begin(); it != studs.end(); it++)
      (*it).print() ;
}
```

I get this error

```
students.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:  
students.cpp:22: error: passing ‘const student’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void student::print()’ discards qualifiers
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_function.h: In member function ‘bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = student]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_tree.h:982:   instantiated from ‘std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator, bool> std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_insert_unique(const _Val&) [with _Key = student, _Val = student, _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<student>, _Compare = std::less<student>, _Alloc = std::allocator<student>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_set.h:307:   instantiated from ‘std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Key, std::_Identity<_Key>, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator, bool> std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const _Key&) [with _Key = student, _Compare = std::less<student>, _Alloc = std::allocator<student>]’
students.cpp:18:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_function.h:227: error: passing ‘const student’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘bool student::operator<(const student&)’ discards qualifiers
```

with

```
     bool operator<(const student & s1) const { return true;}  
     bool operator==(const student & s1) const { return true;}
```

now work!! O_o',

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
class student{
  public:
     student(std::string n){
        name=n;
     }
     void print() const {
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
     }
     bool operator<(const student & s1) const { return true;}
     bool operator==(const student & s1) const { return true;}
  private:
     std::string name;
};
int main(){
  std::set<student> studs;
  studs.insert(student("name01"));
  studs.insert(student("name02"));
  std::set<student>::iterator it;
  for(it = studs.begin(); it != studs.end(); it++)
      it->print() ;
}
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? Whatever you're doing, seems fine. So what is the problem?

Comment: I think you meant to overload `operator==`, not `operator=`.

Comment: I think you mean `bool operator ==` there.

Comment: with overload operator== same error

Comment: Your `operator <` definition violates the requirements of `std::set`, namely it is not a strict weak ordering: it is not irreflexive or antisymmetric.  Also, you probably meant to define `operator ==` (equality comparison), not `operator =` (assignment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a `const` qualifer to your `print` member function:

```
void print() const
{
  std::cout << name << std::endl;
}
```

Objects in an `std::set` are necessarily `const`, since they are used as keys.  When an object (or reference) is constant, you can only call member functions of that object which are declared with the `const` qualifier.

You also want `const` qualifiers on both the `==` and `<` operator overload functions.  (And don't forget to change `=` to `==` as pointed out in the comments.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, though `it->print()` is more intuitive.

A naive world-view is that iterators are a bit like pointers.  There is more to it than that, as explained [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/).

> The most obvious form of iterator is a
>   pointer: A pointer can point to
>   elements in an array, and can iterate
>   through them using the increment
>   operator (++). But other forms of
>   iterators exist. For example, each
>   container type (such as a vector) has
>   a specific iterator type designed to
>   iterate through its elements in an
>   efficient way.

Comment: The error is not related to this usage, see @Charles Salvia's answer for the solution to that.

Answer (score 2):

1. You want operator==, not operator=.
2. Your operator< definition violates the requirements of std::set, and is inconsistent with your operator<. That is, according to your operator<, nothing is equivalent, but according to your operator==, everything is equal. Operator< should define a irreflexive, transitive, and asymmetric (for non-equivalent values) relation.
3. Objects in a set are necessarily const, and so to call a function on such an object that function must be declared with the const qualifier. Specifically, print() should be declared `void print() const`.
4. Similarly, operator< should be declared with the const qualifier. std::set requires that operator< can be called with const objects.  Another valid option would be to make operator< a non-member function and to take both objects by value (bad) or const reference (good).
5. While not required in your example, operator== should also be declared with the const qualifier.

Answer (score 1):

Write your `print()` function like this:

```
void print() const //<---- note this 'const'
{
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
}
```

Now your code should work now. :-)

By the way, such functions with `const` keyword appearing on the right side, are called const member function, as they cannot change any member-data of the class.

See this FAQ: [[18.10] What is a "const member function"?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.10)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
class Boxer{
    public:
        string name;
        int strength;
};
struct Comp{
    bool operator()(const Boxer& a, const Boxer& b){
        return a.strength > b.strength;
    }
};
int main(){
    Boxer boxer[3];
    boxer[0].name="uday", boxer[0].strength=23;
    boxer[1].name="manoj", boxer[1].strength=33;
    boxer[2].name="rajiv", boxer[2].strength=13;

    set< Boxer, Comp> s;
    s.insert(boxer[0]);
    s.insert(boxer[1]);
    s.insert(boxer[2]);
    set< Boxer, Comp>::iterator it = s.begin();
    Boxer b = *it;
    cout<<b.name;
    //result is Manoj

    return 0;
}
```